# Can't boot Windows 8.1 DVD

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I have an HP Pavilion 15-p097tx Notebook PC. I planned to dual boot it with Ubuntu 14.04. While installing Ubuntu, I accidently selected delete everything option. The recovery partition was also deleted. Now I want to install Windows again. I have downloaded ISO image of it from Microsoft Dreamspark. I have made a bootable disc from it. But the disc is not booting. I have also configurated the BIOS Settings. I tried Ubuntu Live DVD. It was working fine.

So, what should I do now?

Comment: Will it boot on another PC? Use F9 at the hp logo at boot and select the cd/dvd drive as boot device. You can also order HP recovery media by calling HP at 1-800-474-6836.

Comment: Software downloads from MS Dreamspark doesn't always work as the should, have you tied it with a offical ISO?

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob Not yet but I am going to try it now.

Comment: @Moab Yes, I have an assembled PC with dual-boot. It is working fine. And when I press F9, I see boot menu options(2 options). One is ubuntu  (HGST HTS541010A9E680) and the other one is Boot from EFI file. but, it contains only ubuntu efi and not DVD.

Comment: @Moab Can I use someone else's HP recovery media?

Comment: @rohit15079 HP recovery media is system locked to a specific hardware profile so you cannot interchange recovery discs with pc's. HP Recovery checks the bios for the hardware tattoo (motherboard id), it will not run if there is a mismatch. Media must be for the same model of pc.

Comment: I am able to boot Windows in my laptop by bootable hp usb 8 GB. ISO image was downloaded from Microsoft reamspark. I borrowed it from a friend. Neither my pendrive nor dvd was booting. I don't know why and how, it booted in my laptop. Then I installed Windows, and then Ubuntu. Now, both are working fine.

Comment: @Moab the number you have given for HP don't work in India.

Comment: @rohit15079 see this page https://softwaresupport.hp.com/support-contact-information